# getting an error in aireplay-ng in kali linux

Tags: wifi, kali-linux

When I was testing penetration testing on my router using kali linux, I followed all the steps from this [link](http://lewiscomputerhowto.blogspot.in/2014/06/how-to-hack-wpawpa2-wi-fi-with-kali.html). In the step where you have to enter the router's bssid and client's bssid in aireplay-ng command I'm getting the following command 
`aireplay-ng -0 2 -a 10:FE:ED:2E:5E:20 -c 08:3E:8E:CC:14:A7 mon7`

```
09:00:33 Waiting for beacon frame (BSSID: 10:FE:ED:2E:5E:20) on channel -1 
09:00:33 Couldn't determine current channel for mon7, you should either force the operation with --ignore-negative-one or apply a kernel patch 
Please specify an ESSID (-e) the channel is -1.
```

But the channel I was capturing was some other channel. I'm getting this every time I try. Please help with this -1 channel and how to fix this

Answer (score 1):

From the [kali forum](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?22192-The-fixed-channel-negative-one-issue-when-using-Airodump-ng-and-Kali1-08): run it with `--ignore-negative-one` or `--ig`

Comment: you mean, like the error response suggested? :)

Comment: Haha, I guess it's even more obvious then I thought...